# Численное решение ОДУ Си

Tags: c

Написал с горем пополам программу, находящую решение уравнения методом Эйлера и Рунге с точностью шага 0.1 и 0.05. Программа выводит значения x/y в файл csv. Там идет дальнейшее построение графика. Само уравнение y'=2y+3 ; y(0)=3. Значения она ищет верные, но почему-то грешит со знаками. Прошу знатоков и профессионалов помочь с этой проблемой. на форум обращаюсь впервые. Заранее благодарю!
в программе стоит уравнение y'= 2x для проверки

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<cmath> 
FILE *File;
double F(double x, double y){
    return 2*x;
}
double eiler(double x, double y, double h){

    return  (y + h*(F(x + h / 2, y + (h / 2)*(F(x, y)))));
}
double runge(double x, double y, double h){
    double k1 = F(x, y);
    double k2 = F(x + h / 2, y + (h*k1 / 2));
    double k3 = F(x + h / 2, y + (h*k2 / 2));
    double k4 = F(x + h, y + (h*k3));
    return (y + (h / 6)*(k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4));
}
void start(double *a, double *b){
    printf("\tEnter left point:\t");    scanf("%lf", a);
    printf("\tNow right point:\t"); scanf("%lf", b);
}
void main(){
    double a, b, h[2] = { 0.1, 0.05 }, x[2] = { 0.0,0.0 }, y[4] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    char met = '0';
    int i = 0;
    start(&a, &b);
    File = fopen("C:\\Users\\pavli\\Desktop\\учеба\\3 семестр\\программирование\\4\\4 sol.csv", "w");
    fprintf(File, "h=0.1; ; ;;h=0.05\n");
    fprintf(File, "x;Eiler;Runge-Kutt;;x;Eiler;Runge-Kutt;");
    y[0] = eiler(x[0], y[0], h[0]);
    y[1] = runge(x[0], y[1], h[0]);
    y[2] = eiler(x[1], y[2], h[1]);
    y[3] = runge(x[1], y[3], h[1]);
    for (x[0] = 0, x[1] = 0; x[1]+ h[1] > a ;)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0){
            y[0] = eiler(x[0], y[0], h[0]);
            y[1] = runge(x[0], y[1], h[0]);
            y[2] = eiler(x[1], y[2], h[1]);
            y[3] = runge(x[1], y[3], h[1]);
            fprintf(File, "\n%lf;%lf;%lf;;%lf;%lf;%lf", x[0], y[0], y[1], x[1], y[2], y[3]);
            x[1] -= h[1];
        }
        else{
            y[2] = eiler(x[1], y[2], h[1]);
            y[3] = runge(x[1], y[3], h[1]);
            fprintf(File, "\n%lf;%lf;%lf;;%lf;%lf;%lf", x[0], y[0], y[1], x[1], y[2], y[3]);
            x[0] -= h[0];
            x[1] -= h[1];
        }
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    x[0] = 0.0; x[1] = 0.0; y[0] = 0.0; y[1] = 0.0; y[2] = 0.0; y[3] = 0.0;
    for (x[0] = 0, x[1] = 0; x[1] < b + h[1];)
    {

        if (i % 2 == 0){
            y[0] = eiler(x[0], y[0], h[0]);
            y[1] = runge(x[0], y[1], h[0]);
            y[2] = eiler(x[1], y[2], h[1]);
            y[3] = runge(x[1], y[3], h[1]);
            fprintf(File, "\n%lf;%lf;%lf;;%lf;%lf;%lf", x[0], y[0], y[1], x[1], y[2], y[3]);
            x[1] += h[1];
        }
        else{
            y[2] = eiler(x[1], y[2], h[1]);
            y[3] = runge(x[1], y[3], h[1]);
            fprintf(File, "\n%lf;%lf;%lf;;%lf;%lf;%lf", x[0], y[0], y[1], x[1], y[2], y[3]);
            x[0] += h[0];
            x[1] += h[1];
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ошибка найдена и заключалась в  чередовании знаков внутри самих функций